# SEO of Pagination using rel="next" rel="prev" HTTP Headers

Tags: seo, pagination, http-headers

I am trying to perform some SEO on a pagination control I have on a website.

Following the [Google guidelines](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html), I would like to add link rel=next/prev i.e. `<link href="/search/results?page=2" rel="next" />` to the `<head>` of my search results page.

Unfortunatley, due to a design decision / limitation of MVC3 with rendering [sections and defining their content within Partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with-r/7556594#7556594), I'm unable to do this.

**So my question is** - can I replicate the aforementioned functionality by adding a  "Link" HTTP header, i.e. `Link: <http://www.example.com/search/results?page=2>; rel="next"` to the response and therefore not have to add the `<link>` tags in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [answered by Maile Ohye](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=344378292ff91e8d&hl=en&start=45).

> @estrik: We support rel=”next” and rel=”prev” in the HTTP header. For example, for page=2 of an article, you could respond with the HTTP header:
>
> Link: http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1; rel="prev"
>
> Link: http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3; rel="next"

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/YbXqwoyooGM/0XTh-gIxS7YJ) from a Google employee **rel=prev/next in the HTTP header** is supported by Google

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I'm pretty sure they aren't supporting that, as they aren't support having the rel attribute on the anchor either.