# include a section on a page (cshtml) called for "Html.Action"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I call in my page layout to the menu page with "Html.Action" and I have a section for "javascript" for include javascript code:

Shared/layout.chtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/Site.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @RenderSection("javascript", required: false)

</head>

<body>
    <div id="menucontainer">
        @Html.Action("Menu", "Controls")
    </div>

    <div id="main">
    @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but the menu does not come to include in section "javascript":

Controls/Menu.chtml

```
@section javascript
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/Site.Controls.Menu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li class="current">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("WebGrid Sample", "WebGridSample", "Grids")</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

How I can do to include the javascript call in the section "javascript"?

thanks

Comment: Should that be `menu.cshtml` ?

Comment: I am lost behind belief as to your logic. Why do you have a javascript section that is a script reference. Why not skip the "section" part and just have the javascript reference straight in your menu.cshtml file?

Comment: @musefan so that when rendering the page, javascript calls are in the header, instead of appearing on any side

Comment: I can see it will place in the header, but at what benefit?

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with

Comment: @tugberk yes, it gives me a solution, but I have to include the call to the calling script after the pages with "Html.Action"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sections are not supported when calling an MVC view via `@Html.Action` or `@Html.Partial`. Sections are only supported between the view and its immediate layout.