# JavaScript inside Section in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I render section in HEAD od HTML page and PartialView in the middle of the page like the code shows below

```
<html>
<head>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</head>
.....
    @Html.Partial("_MenuAdmin")
</html>
```

In PartialView _MenuAdmin I have some javascript.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Test");
    </script>
}
```

So, the problem is that same JavaScript code doesn't loaded. If instead PartialView I use View JavaScript loaded properly.

How I can load JavaScript in my sample?

Comment: There are some very compelling reasons why you shouldn't put your JS (or at least the majority of it) in the head of your page but instead should move it to the end. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: Take a look here, this may already be answered...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with

Answer (score 1):

`@section` is not supported inside a Partial View, you should use `@Scripts.Render` directly in your view.

Comment: How to use @Scripts.Render in MVC3? I didn't find any solution.

Comment: You didn't specified that you are using MVC3, the @Scripts.Render is a MVC4 feature