# Usage of section possible in RenderAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use a @section {} construct from within a view rendered via Html.RenderAction?
Seems to be impossible?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't have sections inside partial views.

Comment: Seems like it's really by design: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7556594/309821 (great, "Trivial answer converted to comment")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's really by design: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556594/309821