# asp.net exposing all view models data in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

inside my shared/.master file I added this code to serialize all the models data to a JS object.

```
<script>
    var Model = <%=Model.ToJson()%>;
</script>
```

I have others partial views included in my .master page  `<% Html.RenderPartial("header"); %>`

How can I dynamically serialize all the INCLUDED  partial views models data also?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately partial views aren't really designed to handle stuff like this (see [Darin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556594/1080891) plus following comments for more info.)

I'd recommend using AJAX calls to get the data you need, rather than using asp.net models.