# java script is not getting added if i write script tag in section

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing a MVC4 application in which I am loading the script in partial view as it partial view specific script. If I write script tag in `@section scripts` then not getting added on page, but if I remove the `@section Scripts` then it works fine below is the code in partial view

```
@section scripts
{    
    <script>
        jQuery.cachedScript('@Url.StaticContent("myscript.js", false)');
    </script>       
}
```

above code does not work where as if I write it as below script

```
<script>
    jQuery.cachedScript('@Url.StaticContent("myscript.js", false)');
</script>
```

why it is not taking the reference?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `@section Scripts` doesn't work for partial views. There are two workarounds besides standard `<script>` tag approach:

1. Move the `@section Scripts` into a view page that contains the partial view, and place `@RenderSection` on a layout page, e.g.:

_Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

View.cshtml

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        jQuery.cachedScript('@Url.StaticContent("myscript.js", false)');
    </script>
}
```

2. Use a custom HTML helper extension for your partial view with this code (credits to Erik Philips on [How to render a Section in a Partial View in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764936/how-to-render-a-section-in-a-partial-view-in-mvc3), using `TagBuilder` instead of `String.Format` for tag rendering):

   ```
   public static class RenderJavaScript
   {
       private const String jsViewData = "RenderJS";

       public static void IncludeJS(this HtmlHelper helper, String content)
       {
           List<String> contentList = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[RenderJavaScript.jsViewData] as List<String>();
           if (contentList != null && contentList.Count > 0)
           {
               if (!contentList.Contains(url))
               {
                   contentList.Add(url);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               contentList = new List<String>();
               contentList.Add(url);
               helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(RenderJavaScript.jsViewData, contentList);
           }
       }

       public static MvcHtmlString RenderJS(this HtmlHelper helper)
       {
           var result = new StringBuilder();

           List<String> scriptList = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[RenderJavaScript.jsViewData] as List<String>();
           if (scriptList != null && scriptList.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (String script in scriptList)
               {
                   // start <script> tag
                   TagBuilder startScript = new TagBuilder("script");
                   startScript.MergeAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); // optional
                   startScript.MergeAttribute("src", script); // required src attribute
                   result.AppendLine(startScript.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

                   // end </script> tag
                   TagBuilder endScript = new TagBuilder("script");
                   result.Append(endScript.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
               }
           }

           return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
       }

       // rendering inner text instead of using src attribute
       public static MvcHtmlString CustomJS(this HtmlHelper helper)
       {
           var result = new StringBuilder();

           List<String> contentList = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[RenderJavaScript.jsViewData] as List<String>();
           if (contentList != null && contentList.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (String text in contentList)
               {
                   // start <script> tag
                   TagBuilder startScript = new TagBuilder("script");
                   startScript.MergeAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); // optional
                   startScript.SetInnerText(text);
                   result.AppendLine(startScript.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

                   // end </script> tag
                   TagBuilder endScript = new TagBuilder("script");
                   result.Append(endScript.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
               }
           }

           return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```

To add scripts on views or partial views, add the `IncludeJS` method either with script content:

```
@{
    Html.IncludeJS(jQuery.cachedScript('@Url.StaticContent("myscript.js", false)'););
}
```

or using script path:

```
@{
    Html.IncludeJS(@Url.StaticContent("myscript.js", false));
}
```

Then append either `RenderJS` or 'CustomJS' method on Layout page:

```
@Html.RenderJS()
@Html.CustomJS()
```

Related problems:

[How to add a script in a partial view in MVC4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114084/how-to-add-a-script-in-a-partial-view-in-mvc4)

[ASP MVC Define Section in Partial View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876538/asp-mvc-define-section-in-partial-view)