# MVC validation doesn't work on partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a partial view containing a user creation form. When I call that form within a main view using `@Html.Partial("_CreateUser")`and attempt to submit it empty, none of the Data annotation validations work. However if I return that partial view by itself to the browser, and try it again, validation messages work just fine.  Any suggestions would be appreciated. Code is below.

**ViewModel**

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name.")]
        [Range(2,12, ErrorMessage = "First name must be between {1} and {2}   
        characters in length.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set;  }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a last name.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
```

**Partial View Snippet**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "OpsManagement"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

   <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                            <!--- First Name -->
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">         
                            <!--- Last Name -->
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

  </div>
}
  @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  }
```

**Main View**

```
<div id="newUserPartialView" class="collapse">
             @Html.Partial("_CreateUser")
          </div>
```

Comment: Partial view does not support defining section. You'll have to put that in the main view. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876538/asp-mvc-define-section-in-partial-view)

Comment: @noriMonsta Thank you! That did it.