# How to fix scripts un rendering while navigating through AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i created a function in javascript that navigates to each view with ajax, the problem is when i navigate to page that contains datatable or any javascript plugin it shows an error.
i will put samples of my code below

this is the navigating function

```
  function LoadAjaxURL(url) {

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {

                $('#mainDiv').html(response);
                history.replaceState('', '', url);
            }
        })
    }
```

all my scripts are wrapped in

```
@section pagespecific {


}
```

in layout i'm rendering the scripts form partial view

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Scripts", RenderSection("pagespecific", false)); }
```

in my viewStart i'm checking if request is ajax or not

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    Layout = null;
}
else
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

i need to navigate using ajax and fully render the scripts without getting errors so that the pulgin's will work

Comment: And what about errors? You didn't specify what are these errors that you're getting

Comment: Is the element `#mainDiv` the parent of the element(s) rendered by the `_Scripts` partial?

Comment: Just a reminder: sections are not supported inside partial views - you must put them inside a view page. Probably your scripts not loaded because they're wrapped inside sections in partial view.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric the problems are the scriptes are not render while i'm navigating through ajax, so all my pulgins like datatable ..etc are not workin

Comment: @Richard  yes its

Comment: i will try any i will give you a replay @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Moving the scripts outside the markup loaded via AJAX will make things much easier. For a start any expressions after the `$('#mainDiv').html(response);` won't have been deleted...

Comment: The problem might be exactly the one @TetsuyaYamamoto mentions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183462/use-section-in-partial-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use section in partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183462/use-section-in-partial-view)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what exactly your problem is, but I assume that it is about JavaScript plugins and files that are not fetched before your inline scripts are executed, so their functions & ... wouldn't be recognized by your inline scripts.
To solve such issues, you could use `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
<script>    
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // All .js files and plugin are now completely loaded & you could use them...
    };
</script>
```

Note: By the way, you could exclude your scripts from that section when you're sending Ajax request. Because when you don't have a layout, you don't have any sections.

Please let me know if it helps you or not.