# Can you use @section in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to use the @section within a partial view so that what is included is only in one file. Will this work? This approach doesn't seem to render anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It doesn't work.  You have to use it in the base .cshtml page.