# Is there an alternative for @sections in a partial view using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Continuing on this question [Can you use `@section` in a partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126986/can-you-use-section-in-a-partial-view), where the answer is no, I'll know if there is an alternative way to use `@section` in a partial view.

I'll know this because I've got an wysiwyg editor *(named CK editor)* that I'll use multiple times. This need some scripts that I wouldn't repeat every time on each page. I'll keep it dry.

I'll also that the script tags are on the bottom of the rendered page *(in the browser)*.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates

Comment: Perhaps you could use custom HTML helpers like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823912/181087)...? Do note it is also possible to make [templated HTML helpers](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm).