# MVC - async Task<PartialViewResult>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

How to call child action (render partial) to _layout?
MVC not support async for Partial View?

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> _Notification()
{
    var data = new List<UserNotification>();
    string apiNotificationUrl = APIProvider.APIGenerator("UserNotification", new List<string> { "UID" }, true, _userSession.UID);
    try
    {
        //data = await Task.Run(() => APIProvider.Authorize_Get<List<UserNotification>>(_userSession.Token, apiNotificationUrl));
        data = await APIProvider.Authorize_Get<List<UserNotification>>(_userSession.Token, apiNotificationUrl);
        if (data == null) new List<UserNotification>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return PartialView(data);
}
```

View

```
@Html.Action("_Notification", "Home")
```

Comment: I think answer of your question in below side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134127/how-to-render-mvc-child-action-partialview-into-layout-rendersection