# JQuery/JS in MVC PartialViews?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

If I use `@section scripts` in partial view. page is not rendering script. But If remove `@section scripts` js rendering to the page. What is the difference? Can't I use directly `<Script>` in partialviews? not good practice?

```
 @section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#SideMenu > li").each(function () {
            //Find the inner element with active class
            $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: not a good practice.  Better to put your code in a function on the main view and call the function after the partial is loaded

Comment: But I have sidemenu is partialview which is in _Layout file. If I use @section in _layout Partialview will not invoke. This is common menu for all views. So I kept in _layouts. Now how to manage it.

Comment: then you should put your script in a separate file and make sure that it is also included in the layout page.  You should still not have script on your partial view

Answer (score 1):

If your "scripts" section is defined in your _Layout page, then it would not generate this section since partial views do not invoke the _Layout view.

Typically you'd want to include all the necessary jquery code in your main view, as this will affect any partial views that are initially created with the view.  Now if you have a partial view that is called after view creation, you can simply add your  tags to the bottom of the partial view.

Comment: But I have sidemenu is partialview which is in _Layout file. If I use @section in _layout Partialview will not invoke. This is common menu for all views. So I kept in _layouts. Now how to manage it

Comment: I would forget about using @section in your partials and simply add your <script> code to the bottom of the partial view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Section in partial view doesn't work by design. See this answer for detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556594/1817929