# call javascript function from razor code in partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple `javascript` function in a partial view:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showErrors(data) {
            alert('show errors');
        }

    </script>
}
```

and I need to call this function from my partial view `razor` code. I've tried something like:

```
        @if (Model.ErrorMessage.Count > 0)
        {
            var errors = Html.Partial("_errors", Model.ErrorMessage);
            <script type="text/javascript">showErrors(@errors)</script> 
        }
```

but it's not working. I can't call this function when the page loads because this view will be rendered trough `ajax` call...

Any ideas on how to modify this code so that the javascript method is called from my partial view when it's loaded?

Comment: If you load it via ajax, why don't you just call the function via ajax `success` section?

Comment: because in my ajax call I return a partial view and it is rendered and there is no simple way (or I don't know it) to access the model and to check some stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not have `section` in partial view

so try move

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showErrors(data) {
        alert('show errors');
    }

</script>
```

to your layout or else where and see if it work

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer :-) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with