# Load js file into partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a layout and a view and a partial view. I used my layout in view and in view I load partial view with ajax into view. I used `@RenderSection("Script", required: false)` in my layout for loading my validation js file into partial view with this statement:

```
@section Script{
    <script src="~/Content/js/register.js"></script>
}
```

but after running my project and get view source I saw that file still doesn't load to this page.Then I put   `@section Script{ <script src="~/Content/js/register.js"></script> }` in my View in this way file loaded but any of validation don't run. But when I copy script file code into partial view they are running. Now I want know why when I used file don't run my scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: How you are rendering your `partial view` via `AJAX` ?

Comment: No, After success request I put result into a div like  $('#divreg').html(data);

Comment: What is in your `register.js` file. It referencing elements that are loaded dynamically, in which case are you using event delegation?

Comment: And `@RenderSection()` is not supported in partial views (only the main view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer following code to render your script:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

In your case you have to use this function like this:

After your success request:

```
$('#divreg').html(data);
loadScript("~/Content/js/register.js", function(){
    //initialization code
});
```

Hopefully it resolves your issue.

Thanks

Happy coding :)

Comment: Seriously, all that code just because the code in the script does use event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `@section Scripts{}` in your partial View. It changes nothing and does not render. you'd better use the script file without Section Helper.

Read more:
[Injecting content into specific sections from a partial view ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor View Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with)

Comment: The OP already mention that he is using `@section Scripts{}` on `view page` not in `partial view`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To provide an update to this question, this is currently how we do this internally in Razor partials:

- Button click is fired, partial is rendered in parent view
- The partial view has it's own segment of `js` inside either a file with a `script src="..` tag or locally inside `<script>` tags
- Similar to `document.ready`, an `IFFE` is used to immediately invoke a series of events to load JS widgets etc held within the partial.
- Partial view loads JS correctly.

An example `IFFE` for this would be:

```
<script>
    function ShoutAtMe(str) {

        alert(str)

    }

    (_ => {
        ShoutAtMe("HELLO")
    })();
</script>
```

This script block would be within the `Partial`.