# JavaScript element formatting in Partial view, but not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

A javascript element works in the main view, but doesn't do anything in the partial view. It is formatted correctly, but its not functioning. Any suggestions?

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/

```
<input type='text' class="basic"/>
<em id='basic-log'></em>

$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

I'm trying to include the colorpicker in a partial view.

Comment: could you please add what code is "not functioning" ?

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: This might enlighten you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with . In short : Include that script in your main view.

Comment: Are you load partial on start page ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually call the scripts section in your partial view and execute this method there. That is by design. See Darin's [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with)

What you can do is, keep this method in the main view. You can still conditionally execute this from your partial view if needed.

So in your main view

```
<script>
    var mySettings = mySettings || {};
    mySettings.shouldIShowSpectrum = false;
</script>
@Html.Partial("YourPartialViewNameHere")
@section scripts
{
    <script>
     function enableSpectrum() {
        $(".basic").spectrum({
            color: "#f00",
            change: function (color) {
                $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
            }
        });
    }
    // You can put the above method in an external js file as well.

    $(function() {
        if (mySettings.shouldIShowSpectrum)
        {
            enableSpectrum();
        }

    });
    </script>
}
```

and in your partial view, you can set the `mySettings.shouldIShowSpectrum` value true so that when the page gets rendered it will enable your plugin.

```
<h5>My Partial</h5>
<input type='text' class="basic" />
<em id='basic-log'></em>
<script>
    console.log("going to enable the plugin");
    var mySettings = mySettings || {};
    mySettings.shouldIShowSpectrum = true;
</script>
```