# Render section for meta tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

in my project have two layout page.these two share header and menu partial views.
Now I want to display meta tags dynamically based on page name.
through SECTION I can able to achieve this in view.
But Now I want to do this in partial view like below:
Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("Metatags")
```

Menu.cshtml (under shared folder)

```
@section Metatags{
    <meta name='keywords' content='@ViewBag.MetaKeywords'/>
    <meta name='description' content='@ViewBag.MetaDescription'/>
}
```

`ViewBag` will fill dynamically in controller.

But it is not working. it is not displaying meta details for all page.
any one please help me to resolve this.also is this possible to share SECTION among views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injecting content into specific sections from a partial view ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor View Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556400/injecting-content-into-specific-sections-from-a-partial-view-asp-net-mvc-3-with)

Comment: Sections are not supported in partial views

Comment: Use either script tag or use custom html helper for your partial. Sections only work on view pages, place it inside view instead.