# User Choose Layout MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I've been searching google and here for a few days. I've found how to have certain areas to have different layouts. I'm tyring to find a way to allow the user, who has logged in, to choose the layout of the site they would like, or have it set so the admin is able to set the layout of the site.

For example the main site has a two column layout. Navigation, then main body with a logo up top. Or have the ability to switch to have the navigation and logo up top and just have the main body of the site in the middle.

Any idea on how to allow this in MVC4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the different layout pages.
You can pass the layout page to be used via the viewBag:

```
@{
    Layout = ViewBag.CurrentLayout;
}
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627853/asp-net-mvc-3-sections-and-multiple-layout-levels) maybe helps you to define nested layouts.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the layout which is selected from user and use this while loading a view.

Something like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = ...
    return View("Index", "_SomeSpecialLayout", viewModel);
}
```

Another approach can be passing the selected layout path through `viewdata` or `viewbag`